# How to add same jquery to different div's but with different content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a ToDo list using jquery and html/css. I copied the container twice and set the parents in the second container with different classes. However, whenever I test it out and add anything to one container, it adds it to all of them, even using separate classes. I want each container to have its own list.

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});

//click on x to delete todo

$("ul").on("click", "span", function(event){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event.stopPropagation();

});

$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></span></i>" + todoText + "</li>")
        }

});


$(".fa-pencil").click(function(){
    $("input[type='text'").fadeToggle();
})

//second div - this is where I used the classes 


$(".list2").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});


$(".list2").on("click", "span", function(event2){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    event2.stopPropagation();

});

$(".txt2").keypress(function(event2){
    if(event2.which === 13){
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    $("list.2").append("<li class='li2'><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></span></i>" + todoText + "</li>")
        }

});
```

Heres the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="assets/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Roboto" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css   " href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
<div class= tablets>
<div id="container">
    <h1>To-Do List <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="What are you going to do today?">
    <ul>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Work out 1 hour</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Listen podcast 1 hour</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Learn UX lesson</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <h1>To-Do List <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></h1>
    <input type="text" class= "txt2" placeholder="What are you going to do today?">
    <ul class= "list2">
        <li class="li2"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Work out 1 hour</li>
        <li class="li2"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Listen podcast 1 hour</li>
        <li class="li2"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Learn UX lesson</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: This is the bug:  `$("ul").append` will append to *all* `<ul>` elements.  Specify which one you mean in that line.

Comment: I did in the second part - instead of ul I used the class .list2 - I've added the html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be a simple typo, you have `$("list.2").append` and it should be `$(".list2").append`

Answer (score 0):

You need unique identifiers for your "< ul >" in the code.
Right now the jQuery is targeting all "< ul >" elements instead of the unique ones.

Comment: I added classes to the first and second list and it's still not working.

Comment: Ok it works with different classes, I had a typo earlier. Is there another way to minify the code to shorter tense or do I have to copy and paste the same code again with different classes

Answer (score 0):

you are appending to all < ul tags
to add to only one ul you have to write

```
 $(this).siblings("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></span></i>" + todoText + "</li>")
```

instead of

`$("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></span></i>" + todoText + "</li>")`